# Is it possible to invalidate Text only, but not background image on a custom View on android?

Tags: android, view, ondraw, invalidation

My `CustomView` draws some polygons and the `title text` is located at the centre of a view. As the application runs, I need to change the title text of these views frequently. Of course, I can invalidate after setting a new text so that the application will redraw everything - polygons, colors, and finally the new text - but I am just wondering if there is a clever way that only invalidates the title text, leaving all background `polygons` untouched. The current code looks like this:

```
public CustomView extends View {

    private Path mPolygon1;
    private Path mPolygon2;
    // .. more polygons

    private String mTitleText;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Draws all images
        canvas.drawPath(mPolygon1, mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPolygon2, mPaint);
        // ... more polygon drawing

        canvas.drawText(mTitleText, 0, mTitleText.length(), mTextPaint);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitleText = title;
        invalidate();           // more clever way????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use invalidate(Rect) or invalidate(left, top, right, bottom)

[Here is a link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate(android.graphics.Rect)) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know such method exists. Sometimes, there are too many methods for a single object so that it is hard to find the right method that I'm looking for....

Comment: It is one of the problems in Android, as for me. There are tons usefull methods. But it's hard to remember anything.